# Grunt watch is not catching changes

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, watch

I have my first Gruntfile working with regards to uglifying files, concat and imagemin. When I run grunt from CL, it runs as normal and looks just fine however, when I change and save a file, it is not caught by "watch", which is still running. Any help would be appreciated as my code looks the same as every online example I can find and I cannot see any errors.

Here is the structure of my server dir, which houses all my .js files:

```
├── build
│   ├── production.js
│   └── production.min.js
├── config
│   ├── authStore.js
│   └── passport.js
├── db
│   ├── db.js
│   └── schema.sql
├── models
│   ├── taskModel.js
│   └── userModel.js
├── requestHandler
│   └── userHandler.js
├── routes.js
├── server.js
└── views
    └── index.ejs
```

And here is my Grunt file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt){
  grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  cssmin: {
    target: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'client/css/',
        src: ['*.css'],
        dest: 'client/css/',
        ext: '.min.css'
      }]
    }
  },

  concat: {
    dist: {
      src: [
      'server/**/*.js',
      ],
      dest: 'server/build/production.js',
    },
    dist: {
      src: [
      'client/js/*.js',
      ],
      dest: 'client/build/production.js',
    }
  },

  uglify: {
    build: {
      src: 'server/build/production.js',
      dest: 'server/build/production.min.js'
    },
    build: {
      src: 'client/build/production.js',
      dest: 'client/build/production.min.js'
    }
  },

  imagemin: {
    dynamic: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        // cwd: 'client/img/',
        src: ['client/img/*.jpg'],
        dest: 'client/img/build'
      }]
    }
  },

  watch: {
    options: {
      livereload: true,
    },
    scripts: {
      files: [
        'client/js/*.js',
        'server/**/*.js'
      ],
      tasks: [
        'concat',
        'uglify'
      ],
      options: {
        spawn: false,
      },
    }

  },

 }) //Closes initConfig

  //Tell grunt to use these plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

  grunt.registerTask('server-dev', function (target) {
  // Running nodejs in a different process and displaying output on the main console
  var nodemon = grunt.util.spawn({
       cmd: 'grunt',
       grunt: true,
       args: 'nodemon'
  });
  nodemon.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
  nodemon.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

  grunt.task.run([ 'watch' ]);
});



  //what happens when you type grunt in CL

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['cssmin', 'uglify', 'imagemin', 'concat', 'watch']);//'watch'
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['concat']);
  //grunt.registerTask('default', ['mochaTest']);
};
```

Comment: What does `grunt watch --verbose` say?

Comment: Going by my above example, watch is waiting for changes on any javascript files in either client or server directories. It should then run concat and uglify tasks and then auto reload the result of the changes to the browser. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I forgot the event option parameters:
event: ['added', 'changed', 'deleted']

Comment: --verbose should list all the files you are watching. Where is your Gruntfile located (relative to your other folders)?

Comment: Gruntfile is located at app root, and all files are in client and server dirs:

App       --> client --> *.js
              --> server --> *.js
package.json
Gruntfile.js